# How to get empty string for datatypes.Date in Gorm if value in database is null

Tags: go, types, go-gorm

I have this model struct:

```
type User struct {
        ID        uint           `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
        Name      string         `json:"name"`
        BirthDate datatypes.Date `json:"birthDate" gorm:"default:null"`
}
```

In field `BirthDate` I am using custom data type `datatypes.Date` provided by Gorm

The problem is, it shows this value `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` in json response, while inside the database the value of `BirthDate` is null.

What I want is it should result in empty string if null, How to achive that?

Comment: datatypes.Date is of type [time.Time](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/datatypes#Date) and hence would return the default of time.Time. To be able to get empty string it has to be of type string

Comment: You could use a pointer (`*datatypes.Date`) to differentiate `null`/`nil` and valid dates.

Comment: plz test it with pointer